# Programmatically get movie name from hulu url?

Tags: html, http, web-scraping, web, url

I am using JavaScript.

Is there any programmatic way to fetch the movie name from a hulu url?

For example for the url

> https://www.hulu.com/watch/78974b54-1feb-43ce-9a99-1c1e9e5fce3f

The response should be

```
My Favorite Girlfriend
```

The URL itself is just a uuid. I tried to fetch the page and look at the http response headers, html meta tag, but there is nothing useful.

Comment: add the code you had tried

Comment: Did you send this request based on an exposed API? If so please do share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the document returned from that URL there is a script tag that contains the information you need:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json"> 
   {"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Movie","name":"My Favorite Girlfriend","description":"A chef's life gets complicated when he falls for a beautiful young woman who has multiple personalities.",
...
</script>
```

Using the npm package cheerio and some javascript to parse this:

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const getMovieName = async (url) => {

    const htmlContent = await (await fetch(url)).text();

    // Load the HTML content into cheerio
    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlContent);

    // Find the script element with type "application/ld+json"
    const scriptElement = $('script[type="application/ld+json"]').first();

    if (scriptElement) {
        try {
            // Parse the JSON content
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(scriptElement.html());

            // Access the parsed data
            console.log(jsonData.name);
            return jsonData.name;

            // You can access other properties as well
            // For example: jsonData['@context'], jsonData['@type']
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error);
        }
    } else {
        console.error('Script element not found');
    }
}

getMovieName("https://www.hulu.com/watch/78974b54-1feb-43ce-9a99-1c1e9e5fce3f")
```

Comment: wow, good catch. I am using JavaScript

Comment: I've updated this with a full nodejs example, if you found this helpful please mark it as complete :)

Comment: thank you so much @FuzzyLogic12 . it does work and i learned from it.